# How to insert a line into a crontab AFTER a key word or string via script

Tags: awk, sed, grep, scripting, cron

I understand there is a lot of documentation on editing crontabs via script, and I can do this by adding an entry with the following command:

```
line="* * * * * /my/folder/script.sh"
( crontab -l ; echo "$line" ) | crontab -
```

However, myself and a few others each have our own "sections" in our crontab under a superuser.

How can I insert this line under a keyword or string, such as underneath the line containing `SPECIAL_JOB` so as not to disturb others' sections and entries? I don't want to just keep appending new jobs at the bottom of the crontab.

The cron entry would look like this:

```
# SPECIAL_JOB
* * * * * /my/folder/script.sh
```

Ideally, I would delete the previous entry at this line to keep a single, fresh entry using this:

```
#remove entry
crontab -l | grep -ve '/my/folder/script.sh' | crontab -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This inserts after all `# SPECIAL_JOB` lines the `$line` string.

```
crontab -l | sed '/# SPECIAL_JOB/a'"$line" | crontab -
```

Comment: Works great -- quotes confused me until now. Thanks!

Comment: You could also consider using the sed `c` (**c**hange) command, to avoid the need for a separate step to delete the old entry e.g. `sed -e '/^# SPECIAL_JOB/{n; c'"$line" -e '}'`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any issues with special characters in the replacement text, I would put the new cron entry into a file, named for example `new-entry`, then use:

```
{ crontab -l | sed '/^# SPECIAL_JOB/{
n
r /path/to/new-entry
d
}' } | crontab -
```

I made a minor change of subshell parenthesis `(` ... `)` to simple curly braces `{` ... `}`, because there's no real need to create a subshell; no harm, either!

I then use sed to parse the incoming text; it looks for a line that starts with `# SPECIAL_JOB` and then performs three actions:

1. prints the current line then reads in the next line (this lets `# SPECIAL_JOB` be printed)
2. `r` reads in the job from your file
3. `d` then deletes the line that used to follow `# SPECIAL_JOB` -- the old job.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using ansible un a larger scale.

Comment: I did not down-vote you, but think that you, as a new contributor, could benefit from a word of explanation: **1)** `ansible` is not called for or expected here. You can acheive what OP requested without resorting to such extraneous pakage. **2)** You did not address OP's specific query.  **3)** you did not provide reference and/or detailed instructions to back-up your answer. **In other  words** you did not create or contribute value with your answer. We hope that you will continue to participate in the forum, adhering to its guidelines (https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for Q/A.